# SQL Select statement which shows row-specific count information?

Tags: sql, select, count

I need some SQL help ..

Suppose I have 2 tables: `Customers` and `Products`.

Now, I want to see a SQL statement that will show me these two columns:

```
Customer  |   Number of orders placed
```

How do I do that ?

The second column is a non-existent column, which is showing a number which states how many orders that customer has placed.

For example:

```
Customer  | Number of orders placed
--------  | -----------------------
John      |              23
Jack      |               5
Mary      |              12
```

etc ..

What's the SQL for this kind of a select ?

Comment: you probably need to have another table for starters. "orders" - the one that will link customers to products

Answer (score 0):

JOIN. This is just making up your column names since tables weren't given.

```
   SELECT 
        c.Name,
        myOrders = COUNT(o.id)
   FROM Customers c
   INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON c.id = o.customerId
   GROUP BY c.Name
```

Some quick reading: [JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).  [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the Product table contains a foreign key CustomerID which references the Customer. The resulting query would be

```
select Customers.Name, Count(*)
from   Customers join Products 
       on Customers.CustomerID = Products.CustomerID
```

However, this is just a guess as you forgot to inform us about the relation between the two tables, i.e. how the Products know to which Customer they belong.

Also, but this is a bit picky, you want the number of orders but only have a 'Product' table...